# Issues on Automating Job Application Submission on LinkedIn

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently developing a Chrome extension that will automate job application submission on LinkedIn. The automation is just clicking the Next, Review, and Submit application buttion below:

[image]

The problem is when I'm doing the auto-click for Submit application button. This always shows:
[image]

Then on the console, 424 error shows.
[image]

Here is the auto-click function on the Next, Review and Submit application buttons.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--primary ember-view")[0].click();
```

I also tried this but no luck:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--primary ember-view")[0];
var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window
});
button.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

Is there a way to automate the buttons with no 424 no problem in the end of the application? Thank you so much in advance!